# Modify the third (context) parameter in a filter?

Tags: filters, cookies

I understand that the following filter modifies the parameters of the authentication cookies, in fact I have managed to modify its value since it is the first parameter $cookie, but what I need is to modify the parameter $expiration that translates to Expires in the cookie.

So how could I modify the third parameter $expiration given that only $cookie can be returned and the rest seem to be in context?

```
add_filter( "auth_cookie", "modify_auth_cookie_defaults", 10, 5 );
function modify_auth_cookie_defaults($cookie, $user_id, $expiration, $scheme, $token) { 

return str_replace( $expiration, DAY_IN_SECONDS, $expiration );
}

add_filter( "auth_cookie", "modify_auth_cookie_defaults", 10, 5 );
function modify_auth_cookie_defaults($cookie, $user_id, $expiration, $scheme, $token) { 
$expiration = YEAR_IN_SECONDS
return $expiration; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the parameters of a filter like that, that's not what they're there for. In the source code it'll look something like this:

```
$cookie = apply_filters( $cookie, $user_id, $expiration, $scheme, $token );
```

It's explicitly looking for the value of `$cookie`. If you return the value for `$expiration`, things will break. The extra parameters are there so filtering can be restricted to specific situations, like only for a certain user.

However you can modify the expiration with a different approach. The function that contains the `auth_cookie` filter is [`wp_generate_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_auth_cookie/). This function appears to only be used (in core at least) by the function [`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/). If we look at that function, we can see the [`auth_cookie_expiration`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/) filter. This filter is what creates the `$expiration` value that is passed to the original `auth_cookie` filter.

TL;DR, use the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter instead.